# Rotate Mapbox Map depending on user's orientation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mapbox

I'm looking to make a simple navigation application which always rotates depending on the user's orientation. I've seen some answers for android but haven't found anything that works in Swift yet.

I tried the following however it is not working for me and am unsure if this is even getting me closer to what I'm looking for.

```
let newCam = MGLMapCamera()
newCam.heading = 90
mapView.setCamera(newCam, animated: true)
```

I'm quite new to Xcode and Swift and am having trouble understanding so go easy on me!

Comment: What will rotate?

Comment: The map itself, so if a point on the map relative to the user's location is towards north for example, the map will rotate so that the point is always actually pointing north no matter what orientation the user/phone is in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mapView has a property: `direction`, that you can set. Changing the value of this property updates the map view immediately. If you want to animate the change, use the `-setDirection:animated:` method instead. Or you could use the following method:

```
func setCenter(_ centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, zoomLevel: Double, direction: CLLocationDirection, animated: Bool)
```

Where direction is

> The new direction for the map, measured in degrees relative to true north.

You could call this periodically, calculating the offset from north, using the startUpdatingHeading method on CLLocationManager. There is another version of this method with a completion handler if you needed that.

** EDIT **

You can use the following code to extract the direction the phone is oriented. It prints to the console here (from a real device naturally) but you could take the figure (degrees) and in determine in your code how far from north the device is pointing.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager:CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading heading: CLHeading) {

    print(heading.magneticHeading)
}
}
```

I'm off to the dentist now but will check back in an hour or so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems promising. Forgive my lack of experience, but could you explain how to implement it in a little more detail?

Comment: Work like a charm !

Answer (score 4):

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading heading: CLHeading) {
    // set mapView's direction to user's orientation, i.e. magnetic heading
    mapView.direction = heading.magneticHeading
}
```